# Solving functional equation $f(x)\cdot f(y)-xy=f(x)+f(y)-1$

Tags: functions

As in the title. Substituting $y=x$ we get:
$$ f(x)^2-x^2=2f(x)-1 $$
after rearranging, we get:
$$ f(x)(f(x)-2)=(x+1)(x-1) $$
And I rather cannot assume that e.g. $f(x)=x+1$ and $f(x)-2=x-1$, so what should I do now?

Comment: If you assume that $f(x) = x+1$, then the equality would hold true?

Comment: surely that's a quadratic you can solve to get $f(x)$ ?

Comment: Oh, and I didn't notice that. Great, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in your first step you had the following equation:

$$f(x)^2-x^2=2f(x)-1$$

Instead of factoring, if we rearrange all the terms on one side we get:

$$f(x)^2 - 2f(x) - x^2 + 1 = 0$$

Note we have a quadratic, with $f(x)$ acting like our $x$ and the term $1-x^2$ being our constant term.

Solving, we get:

$$f(x) = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4 -4(1-x^2)}}{2}$$
$$ = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4 - 4 + 4x^2)}}{2}$$
$$ = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4x^2}}{2}$$
$$ = \frac{2 \pm 2x}{2}$$

Therefore, we get $2$ solutions for $f(x)$:

$$f(x) = \frac{2 + 2x}{2} = 1+x$$
$$f(x) = \frac{2 - 2x}{2} = 1-x$$

Answer (score 3):

Consider $g(x)=f(x)-1$. Then we can write the identity as
$$
(g(x)+1)(g(y)+1)-xy=g(x)+g(y)+1
$$
or
$$
g(x)g(y)=xy
$$
I think you can go on from here.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

The equality is equivalent to 
$$(1-f(x))\cdot(1-f(y)) = x y$$
and with $h(x) = 1-f(x)$ we have
$$h(x) h(y) = x y$$

with solutions $h(x) \equiv x$ and $h(x) \equiv -x$, so $f(x) \equiv 1-x$ and $f(x) \equiv 1+x$ are the two solutions.